# Connect to LocalDB via SQLCMD in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd, sql-server-localdb

I'm trying to access the "localdb\MSSQLLocalDB" server on my computer through PowerShell with the SQLCMD utility. I'm using PowerShell v5, .NET v5.0, and the server name is `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` when I connect to it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

`PS C:\> sqlcmd -S localdb\MSSQLLocalDB` and `PS C:\> sqlcmd -S .\localdb\MSSQLLocalDB` result in this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server
>   Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>   [xFFFFFFFF].

I queried the server name in Management Studio with `SELECT @@ServerName` and used that after the `-S` in the above command and got the same error.

`PS C:\> sqlcmd -S localdb` gives this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Named Pipes
>   Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]

Other notes: I'm able to connect to the server and work with a database named *testdb01* in a C# console app using `System.Data.SqlClient` with this connection string:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=testdb01;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The casing of the instance name does not matter.

You need to try:

```
sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -d testdb01
```

The "localdb" part needs to be enclosed in parenthesis as that is a special syntax that points to a SQL Server Express LocalDB-specific API that allows for automatic instance start-up upon being referenced in a connection string. The whole instance name needs to be enclosed in double quotes. The command-line shown above works for me, at least outside of PowerShell.

Comment: Including `(localdb)` in parenthesis looks like it separates it as a command, and it gives the following error: _The term 'localdb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program._

Comment: @jmk22 Then try putting the entire server name in double-quotes: `-S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"`. If that doesn't work then we can try escaping the parenthesis. But somehow those parens need to be there.

Comment: The quotations did it, thanks! I've edited your answer to reflect this.